# How to execute custom script on laravel-datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel datatables(https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables).
I want to execute my custom script after processing datatables. I want to register event on one of rendering html dom element. how can I make it?
I try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.someclass').on('change',function(){

    });
});`
```

but it dosn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete. Show an alert when the table has fully loaded

```js
 $('#example').dataTable( {
      "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
      }
    } );
```

Comment: It is needed to wait untill the table has fully loaded because the elements of the datatable are only available for your JS-selectors as soon as the elements are done loading asynchronously.